# Query for maximal number in an INT column works well in phpmyadmin, but not in php code

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to grab the MAX number of an INT column. When I run the query in phpmyadmin, it works fine. But when I put it in my PHP code, it keeps returning 0. I think my problem is I dont know how to grab it from the query properly. Specifically im using mysql_result, but after reading its syntax, I dont know if you can do it this way.

Here is what I got:

```
$query="SELECT MAX(`imageOrder`) FROM images where `gallery` = '$originalGallery'";
$result=mysql_query($query);    
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

I know the above works, but this is where I get lost. How do I get MAX(`imageOrder`) into a PHP variable?

```
$topOrder=mysql_result($result,0);
```

Doesn't work:

```
$topOrder=mysql_result($result,$i,MAX(`imageOrder`));
```

Doesn't work either (looping here BTW).

I am sure you know what I am trying to do. I am trying to grab a single returned value. It should just be a 2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // value
```

The row[0] will contain your maximun.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there:

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(`imageOrder`) as maximages FROM images where `gallery` = '$originalGallery'";
$result = mysql_query($query);    
$num = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $num['maximages'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT MAX(...) AS maximum ...";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo $row['maximum'];
```

Or, if you wan to fetch directly into a variable:

```
list($maximum) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong, but off the top of my head you need to fetch result as if it were a row using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` or something similar.